# ComponentDidMount gets called each time the browser is resized in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I am developing a Web application using React JS. I am a beginner to ReactJS. What I am doing now is getting the data from the remote server making API request and display them on the page.

But the problem is componentDidMount event of the React Component always gets called whenever I resize the browser. I am making the API call in the componentDidMount event. So, whenever I resize the browser, it is making extra calls to the server and refreshing the data. That should not be happening. So, to make sure the API call made only once, I check using a state in the componentDidMount event like this.

```
componentDidMount()
{
    if(!this.state.initialized)
    {
        //Api call
        this.fetchEvents(); 
    }
    this.setState({
        initialized: true
    })
}
```

The above code is still making the api requests to the server and refreshing the data on browser resized. Why it this happening? How to prevent it? Rather than an instant solution to prevent it, I like to understand the inner-working of it.

This is my whole EventListComponent:

```
class EventListComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);   
        this.redirectToCreatePage = this.redirectToCreatePage.bind(this);
        this.redirectToEditPage = this.redirectToEditPage.bind(this);
        this.showDeleteEventConfirmation = this.showDeleteEventConfirmation.bind(this);
        this.closeDeleteConfirmation = this.closeDeleteConfirmation.bind(this);
        this.deleteEvent = this.deleteEvent.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            initialized :false
        }
    }

    componentDidMount()
    {
        if(!this.state.initialized)
        {
            this.fetchEvents(); 
        }
        this.setState({
            initialized: true
        })
    }

    fetchEvents()
    {
        this.props.startFetchingEvents();
        getHttpClient().get('event/list', { })
        .then((response) => {
            this.props.completeFetchingEvent(response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            this.props.errorFetchingEvents();
        });
    }

    redirectToEditPage(event)
    {
        // return alert(event.id)
        this.props.setEditingEvent(event);
        this.props.history.push({ 
           pathname : '/event/'+ event.id +'/edit'
        });
    }

    redirectToAlbum(event)
    {
        this.props.history.push("/event/" + event.code + "/album");
    }

    redirectToCreatePage()
    {
        this.props.history.push('event/create');
    }

    redirectToUploadPage(event)
    {
        this.props.history.push('event/' + event.id + '/file/upload')
    }

    redirectToMatchPhotosPage(event)
    {
        this.props.history.push('/event/' + event.id + '/match/photos');
    }

    showDeleteEventConfirmation(event)
    {
        this.props.promptDeleteConfirmation(event);
    }

    closeDeleteConfirmation()
    {
        this.props.closeDeleteConfirmation();
    }

    deleteEvent()
    {
        this.props.startDeletingEvent(this.props.eventToBeDeleted);
        let body = { id : this.props.eventToBeDeleted.id }
        let path = "event/delete";
        getHttpClient()
        .post(path, body)
        .then((response) => {
            this.props.completeDeletingEvent();
            window.location.reload()
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            this.props.errorDeletingEvent();
        });
    }

    render() {
        let eventWidgets = this.props.events.map((item, index)=> {
            return <Grid key={index} item sm={4} xs={4}>
            <EventWidget 
            showDeleteEventConfirmation={this.showDeleteEventConfirmation.bind(this)}
            redirectToUploadPage={this.redirectToUploadPage.bind(this)}
            redirectToAlbum={this.redirectToAlbum.bind(this)}
            redirectToEditPage={this.redirectToEditPage.bind(this)} 
            redirectToMatchPhotosPage={this.redirectToMatchPhotosPage.bind(this)}
            {...item} />
            </Grid>
        })
        
        return (
        <div className={scss['page-container']}>
        <Button onClick={this.redirectToCreatePage} color="secondary" type="button" variant="raised">Post new event</Button>
 
  

        <BlockUi tag="div" blocking={this.props.requestingEvents}>
        <Grid
        style={{ marginTop: "10px", minHeight: "100px" }}
        spacing={16}
        container
        justify="flex-start"
        >
        
            {eventWidgets}
        
        </Grid>
        </BlockUi>

        
        <Dialog
          open={this.props.showDeleteConfirmationDialog}
          onClose={this.closeDeleteConfirmation}
          aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
          aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
        >
        <BlockUi tag="div" blocking={this.props.deletingEvent}>
          <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">{"Confirmation"}</DialogTitle>
          <DialogContent>
            <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description">
              Are you sure to delete the event? You cannot undo the action.
            </DialogContentText>
          </DialogContent>
          <DialogActions>
            <Button onClick={this.closeDeleteConfirmation} color="primary">
              No
            </Button>
            <Button onClick={this.deleteEvent} color="primary" autoFocus>
              Yes
            </Button>
          </DialogActions>
        </BlockUi>
        </Dialog>
       
        </div>
        );
    }
}



function mapStateToProps(state)
{
    return {
        events: state.eventList.events,
        requestingEvents : state.eventList.requestingList,
        showDeleteConfirmationDialog : state.eventList.showDeleteConfirmationDialog,
        deletingEvent : state.eventList.deletingEvent,
        eventToBeDeleted : state.eventList.eventToBeDeleted
    };
}

function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch)
{
    return bindActionCreators({
        startFetchingEvents: EventListActions.startFetchingEvents,
        completeFetchingEvent: EventListActions.completeFetchingEvents,
        errorFetchingEvents : EventListActions.errorFetchingEvents,
        setEditingEvent: EditEventActions.setEditingEvent,
        promptDeleteConfirmation : EventListActions.promptDeleteConfirmation ,
        closeDeleteConfirmation : EventListActions.closeDeleteConfirmation,
        startDeletingEvent : EventListActions.startDeletingEvent,
        completeDeletingEvent : EventListActions.completeDeletingEvent,
        errorDeletingEvent : EventListActions.errorDeletingEvent
    }, dispatch);
}

EventListComponent.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.shape({
    headerTheme: PropTypes.string
  }).isRequired
};

const enhance = compose(withWidth(), withStyles(themeStyles, { withTheme: true }), connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps))

export default enhance(EventListComponent);
```

Comment: `componentDidMount` is not re-run on resize. Could you include the code where you are using this component that gets remounted on resize?

Comment: I just bought a theme from the Themeforest and using it. So, there is nothing to do with browser resize event?

Comment: Could you post a mini working code? If possible, put it in sandbox. There is something else going on here, like @Tholle said, didMount does not re-run on resize.

Comment: I have updated the question to show code.

Comment: what does the withWidth Hoc do?